# What does this definition, $\bar{Y}= \frac{\sum^M_{i=1}\sum^{N_i}_{j=1} Y_{ij}}{\sum^{M}_{i=1} N_{i}}$, mean?

Tags: sampling, cluster-sample

I am studying the topic of cluster sampling. Within this topic I have learnt that the mean per element is defined as $$\bar{Y}= \frac{\sum^M_{i=1}\sum^{N_i}_{j=1} Y_{ij}}{\sum^{M}_{i=1} N_{i}}$$ $M$ denotes the number of clusters. $N_i$ denotes the size of each cluster. $Y_{ij}$ denotes the elements in every cluster. I do not really understand what this definition means. Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Y_{i,j}$ represents the value of the $j$th element in cluster $i$. So for instance, $\sum^{N_1}_{j=1} Y_{1j}$ represents the sum of all the elements in cluster $1$. More generally, the inner sum represents the sum of all the elements in cluster $i$.

The outer sum loops over all clusters $M$. So the numerator is the sum of the elements *in all clusters*.

The denominator is the total number of elements in *all* clusters. So you're dividing the sum of all the elements by the total number of elements to get the mean value per element.

Comment: thanks, for your explanation. Am I right in saying that the definition states that each element within the dataset is on average Y

Comment: yes, the average of all the elements in the dataset is $\bar{Y}$. personally i find the wording "each element is on average $\bar{Y}$" to be misleading, since there may be no point in the dataset which is exactly $\bar{Y}$, but people will probably understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

This is the usual notion of mean you've become accustomed to. I'm assuming the notation is what's confusing so the denominator should be easier to understand. If there are M clusters and cluster i contains $N_{i}$ elements then summing all M $N_{i} $ clusters gives you the total number of things in your dataset (the "grand N" which I'll call N with no subscript).

Then, by the same logic, the numerator is the sum of the values of Y at those N number of points (it's probably worth looking at the sums and seeing why the number of terms in the numerator is the same as the N from the denominator).

Finally, if the numerator is a sum of N things and we divide this value by N we get back a mean.

Comment: thanks, for your explanation. Am I right in saying that the definition states that each element within the dataset is on average $\bar{Y}$.

Comment: Not as you've stated. The Y's, presumably, are random variables so their expectation is some parameter of the population. That is, under a particular philosophy, there exists a true mean of those Y's but we dont know what it is. The thing you're calculating is the sample mean, the average of the things you got to see. Since you didn't see everything there was to see, your estimate of the mean won't be exact and thus the theoretical mean of Y doesn't have to be the sample mean you calculate.

Comment: I forgot to state that the definition above is the population mean per element.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator is sum of all samples (all $Y$'s). The denominator is total number of samples. So this is the mean of all samples.